# postfix 3.3.0 has fatal error "bad string length 0 < 1"

Tags: ubuntu, email, mysql, postfix

I'm migrating my mail server from an older instance of postfix (3.2.0) to 3.3.0 on Ubuntu.  I'm installing from apt and installation went fine.  I'm in the process of trying to set up my [MySQL connections](http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html), copying them from my old system to this one.

I'm running into a problem when I try to run `postmap -q example@example.com mysql:aliases.cf`.  The error I get is:

```
postmap: fatal: bad string length 0 < 1: aliases.cf_dbname =
```

The file in question (aliases.cf) is simple:

```
hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = postfix_user
password = hunter2
dbname = postfix_db

query = SELECT `destination`
        FROM `mail_aliases`
        WHERE
        `alias_address` = '%u'
        AND `domain` = '%d'
        AND `active` = 1
```

I've done a couple of things to troubleshoot this:

- I've tried adding `options_file` and `options_group` which didn't help.
- Kept `options_file` and `options_group` and removed `hosts`, `user`, and `password.  Didn't work
- Created a hash file (flat file) and that works
- Sent an email to an address in the database (via `sendmail` on the local box) but get this error: `Sep 17 01:06:42 ec21234 postfix/cleanup[4230]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual/aliases.cf lookup error for "example@example.com"`
- Connecting to the database directly with username and password works perfectly.

I've done a bit of google searching and haven't been able to find anything useful.  The closest I could find was [this result](https://it.toolbox.com/question/postfix-error-postmap-fatal-bad-string-length-0-1-dbname-111209) which only loads when viewed with [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:J5iqpF75Kx0J:https://it.toolbox.com/question/postfix-error-postmap-fatal-bad-string-length-0-1-dbname-111209&client=firefox-b-1-d&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1&vwsrc=0).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `mysql` argument for `postmap` wants a path.  When I run the command `postmap -q example@example.com mysql:./aliases.cf`, it works.  Not sure where the path is relative to.  I tried putting the config files in `/` and that didn't work.

The mail log is still showing that there was a lookup error.  I could still use help there.